# How can i get statistics on the empty fields in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
| city | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5 |
|  1   |    a   |        |    b   |    b   |
|  2   |        |        |    c   |        |
|  3   |        |    a   |        |        |
|  4   |    a   |        |        |        |
|  1   |        |    a   |        |    b   |
|  2   |    b   |        |    c   |        |
|  4   |        |    a   |        |        |
|  3   |        |        |    a   |        |
|  2   |    b   |        |        |        |
|  1   |        |    a   |        |    b   |
|  2   |        |        |    a   |        |
|  3   |    a   |        |        |    b   |
|  1   |        |        |    b   |        |
|  1   |    b   |    a   |        |        |
|  2   |        |        |    b   |    b   |
|  1   |    b   |    a   |        |    b   |
```

I need to get here is a list of statistics blank fields with the group on the field "city".

```
| city | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5 |
|  1   |    3   |    2   |    4   |    2   |
|  2   |    3   |    5   |    1   |    4   |
|  3   |    2   |    2   |    2   |    2   |
|  4   |    1   |    1   |    2   |    2   |
```

How can I do this with a python pandas?

Comment: How are you determining the values to fill in?

Comment: @rurp This is count of blank cell by field for this 'city'. eg city 1 have a 3 blank cell in field2, 2 blank cell in field3 etc.

Comment: What do you mean by blank cell? Does that mean NaN or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "city": [1,2,1,2,1,2],
    "field2": [np.nan, "a", np.nan, np.nan, "b", np.nan],
    "field3": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, "b", "a", "b"],
    })
df
```

This is my example data:

```
    city    field2  field3
0   1   NaN NaN
1   2   a   NaN
2   1   NaN NaN
3   2   NaN b
4   1   b   a
5   2   NaN b
```

Now the logic:

```
# define a function that counts the number of `nan` in a series.
def count_nan(col):
    return col.isnull().sum()

# group by city and count the number of `nan` per city
df.groupby("city").agg({"field2": count_nan, "field3": count_nan})
```

This is the output:

```
field2  field3
city        
1   2   2
2   2   1
```

Comment: I prefer using `col.isnull().sum()`.

Comment: Thank. What to do if you want to not null, and the condition? For example `== ""`

Comment: @AndyHayden, your version is more readable and probably even faster.

Comment: @AndyHayden, how do you use?

Comment: @NCNecros, depends. A clean way is to make sure that not available data are encoded by `np.nan` in the first place. `df.replace("", np.nan)`, may help.

Comment: @NCNecros performance is the same, that's just a rewrite for the count_nan function.